# A way to approximate or reexpress the Bernoulli number containing sum in the Euler-Maclaurin approximation of the Riemann-zeta function?

Tags: combinatorics, riemann-zeta, euler-maclaurin

Please examine [the first (and second) equations here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Examples).

I would like to find a way to express the sum containing even Bernoulli numbers as a closed form function (evaluate it) or approximation of it thereof in similar form.

It seems knowledge computation engines struggle with this task, and I'd rather not spend many days searching through various repositories of functions and series involving the Bernoulli numbers and factorials.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, which sum, to achieve what ? $B_n$ satisfies a simple recurrence relation

Comment: $\frac{B_n}{n!}$ are the power series coefficients of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$, they are defined by the recurrence $B_0=1, \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{B_n}{n!} \frac1{(k+1-n)!} = 0$

Comment: @reuns sorry, this is still not terribly clear to me. That sum at the end the formulas equations should not converge.

Comment: Which formula. Use mathjax and clarify what you are talking about.